# Отсутствие ошибки при выходе за пределы массива

Tags: c++

Не понимаю, почему компилятор не выдает ошибки во время исполнении в Visual Studio 2010 с C++ builder 6. Обращаюсь к элементу массива, превышающему его размер.

```
const int dl=2;
int bb[dl];
cout<<"razmer "<<sizeof(bb)<<"\n";

    for (int i=0;i<dl*5;i++)
 {
     bb[i]=i*2;

}

for (int i=0;i<dl*5;i++)
 {
    cout<<bb[i]<<" nomer "<<i<<"\n";

 }
```

Comment: Потому что си++ компиляторам по умолчанию всё равно, выходите ли вы за рамки или нет. Возможно определённые флаги типа -Wall сгенерируют warn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сейчас, это уже не делает ничего криминального, кроме того что Вы обращаетесь к разделу памяти который вам не принадлежит. Можно в него записывать и считывать, но нет гарантий на то, что записав туда что-то, считаете то же самое.

Comment: Или не упадете.

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию компиляторам си/си++ всё равно, выходите ли вы за рамки или нет.

Если вы добавите флаги:

```
-Wall -O2
```

То будет выводить предупреждения. Это правда касается g++, про Visual не уверен, но думаю

```
/Wall /O2 должно сработать.
```

Answer (score 2):

Хотелось бы добавить ко всему выше сказанному следующую цитату из книги:
"Любая проверка корректности доступа средствами C++ существенно замедляет выполнение программы. Поэтому подобные действия оставлены на рассмотрение программистам".

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать динамический массив `std::vector` у него есть два способа обращения к элементам:

- с помощью квадартных скобок [i]
- с помощью `mas.at(i);` - дак вот `at` - генерирует исключение `out_of_range`, если вы обратились за пределеы массива.